# Usar un texto de respuesta para definir un salto de seccion

Tags: html, formularios, google-apps-script

Necesito crear un formulario mediante script, el mismo debería tener la particularidad de estar dividido en varias páginas. La funcionalidad que debo generar es que en la primer pantalla pida el email, y al presionar sobre siguiente debería revisar si el email está en una planilla de Google Sheets, en caso de no estar pasaría a una pantalla donde pida los datos, y de estar se saltaría dicho pedido de datos personales.

Vi que se puede hacer algo similar según que CheckBox se presione, lo que yo necesito es validarlo según que email se escriba.

Comment: Christian deberías tener en cuenta que tu pregunta carece de código alguno, y debería tener un [mcve] . Deberías mostrar que has intentado

Comment: A mí si me parece claro lo que pregunta.

Comment: @AgustinM. No es obligatorio que todas las preguntas tengan código. Por ejemplo, para responder esta pregunta no hace falta que la pregunta incluya código alguno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que sí es entendible tu pregunta, la respuesta es creando una secuencia de comando con 2 parámetros:

1. Tu codigo
2. El HTML del formulario a mostrar ejemplo imagen adjunta.
   [image]

En el primer archivo de codigo vas a colocar la siguiente instrucción:

```js
function doGet(e) {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form.html');
  
  return html;
}
```

En el Form.html vas a crear tu formulario en html con los campos que necesites y le puedes añadir los estilos o lo que prefieras, ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta:

Inicialmente colocas un campo input donde solicites el email y un botón enviar estos dentro de un form, los demás campos le colocas display = "none" a través del ID. Luego de hcer tu validación que supongo que sabes buscar ese email en una base de datos (hoja de calculo) le dices que cambie el valor display none a Hide o block de acuerdo a un condicional IF/else.

Creo que es extensa la explicación si tienes dudas me puedes escribir y te voy ayudando.

Recuerda que debes tener conocimientos en HTML5/CSS3/Javascript.

Comment: Bienvenido Luis. La pregunta trata sobre formularios de Google (Google Forms) no de formularios realizados con una web app de Google Apps Script. Tal vez quieras agregar porque propones el uso de este tipo de formularios como alternativa a los formularios de Google.

Comment: Ruben, el inicio de la pregunta cito literlamente "Necesito crear un Google Form mediante script" y dado que tiene la etiqueta Google Scrip. sugiero ese uso debido a que es casi imposible o tedioso lo que propone a través de Google Form.

Comment: Agrega lo que dices a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

> NOTA: Inicialmente la pregunta trataba sobre Google Forms.

Google Forms / Formularios de Google incluye como característica la validación de datos pero esta no incluye el verificar que el dato capturado esté en una hoja de cálculo de Google.

La validación puede hacerse mediante reglas simples, por ejemplo, que el formato del valor ingresesado sea el de una dirección de correo electrónico, también puedes usar expresiones regulares pero estas tienen algunas limitaciones que no han sido reportadas por usuarios, dudo mucho que en acepte una como expresión regular con varias direcciones de correo, tal vez podría verificar por ejemplo, que sean de cierto dominio.

En relación al control de de navegación, los Google Forms / Formularios de Google sólo incluyen como característica de control de navegación las preguntas tipo

- opción múltiple (botón de radio)
- lista desplegable

Los checkbox no se pueden usar para ello las preguntas tipo casilla de verificación (checkbox) ni tampoco las preguntas de tipo texto corto, texto largo (párrafo), cuadríacula, etc.

Tampoco incluyen la función de agregar JavaScript personalizado